# RxJS/Observable flatMap can return Observable or array

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, flatmap

Can someone explain to me why the `.flatMap` operator can accept a function which returns an `Observable`, or an `array`?

The [official docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) say:

> The FlatMap operator transforms an Observable by applying a function
>   that you specify to each item emitted by the source Observable, **where that function returns an Observable that itself emits items.**

Why can it also return an **array**?

For example, these are both valid:

```
obs$.flatMap((data) => {
    return [];
});

obs$.flatMap((data) => {
    return new Observable<string>();
});
```

But this does not work:

```
obs$.flatMap((data) => {
    return 1;
});
```

Comment: Observables can be thought of as arrays spread over time, so flattening an array is like flattening a synchronous observable. `1` is neither an array nor an observable, so of course it doesn't work.

Comment: `flatMap` is an alias for `mergeMap`. Check the docs and you will see the function can return an observable, a promise, or an array-like value: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap

Comment: Specifically, it can return an `ObservableInput`: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html

Comment: Thanks, that helped my understanding of it a lot, did not realise it was `ObservableInput`. So how can `.flatMap` return an array of Observables? Or is that not possible?

Comment: If you call `flatMap` on an array of observables, you'll get an observable of observables - termed a higher-order observable. There are operators to further flatten such higher-order observables. Look at [`mergeAll`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeAll) and [`concatAll`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatAll). Also, if the links have helped you understand things, you might want to consider adding a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official docs are not relevant because they refer to RxJS 4 and not RxJS 5.

`mergeMap` projection function returns [not just `Observable` but `ObservableInput` interface](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operator/mergeMap.js.html#lineNumber42), which applies to [miscellaneous values that can be converted to observables](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html):

> Arrays can be interpreted as observables that emit all values in array one by one, from left to right, and then complete immediately.

This means that

```
obs$.flatMap((data) => arr)
```

is basically a shorter version of

```
obs$.flatMap((data) => Observable.from(arr))
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me understand it much more